# If not value between does not work. VBA in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, between, vba

I have used Stackoverflow to solve a lot of problems but this one I can´t find the answer to. If not state is not true, ever but even when it should be.

```
dim Val as integer
    for i = 1 to 2
       Val=.Range("N" & i).Value 'Val is 0 for example

       Msgbox(Val) 'to debug what the value is and this example it is 0

       If not (300<=Val<=500) then 'this statement is never true even if Value=0
           'Do stuff
       End If

    next i
```

Comment: There is no number that makes this statement True:  `If Not (300 <= myValue <= 500) Then...`  Are you trying to say "if the number is not between 300 and 500?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
for i = 1 to 2
   Val=.Range("N" & i).Value 'Value is 0 for example

   Msgbox(Val) 'to debug what the value is and this example it is 0

   If Val >= 300 And Val<=500 then ' check if Val is between 300 and 500
       'Do stuff
   End If

next i
```

Renamed your variable to `Val` to distinguish between it and the `.Value`. property

Comment: Smart renaming it to Val.

However this did not work :(

Comment: Exactly what did not work? Did you try after my edit? Please use my entire code, I edited the conditional statement as well in my first post as well.

Comment: the if statement is still not true :(